# How to get MIME type base64 encoded string in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

When I convert the data to `base64`, it gives a single line of `base64` string.

```
image = body.toString('base64');
```

How can I get `base64` string used in MIME types which is wrapped at every 76 characters?

Is there any default method in node to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in method in nodejs for encoding to base64 with line breaks. But there is [`mimelib`](https://github.com/andris9/mimelib) library to achieve this:

**To add line breaks**

```
mimelib.foldLine(str, 76)
```

**To encode to base64 with line breaks**

```
mimelib.encodeBase64(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

To break the resulting base-64 string into lines of no more than 76 characters, one can use replace(), e.g.,

```
body.toString('base64').replace(/.{76}/g, '$&\n')
```

`.` = match any character other than newline
`{76}` = repeat that match exactly 76 times, i.e., split the string into 76-character chunks
`g` = globally, i.e., keep going until out of data in the string
`$&` = insert the matched substring
`\n`= followed by a newline